# Elixir, Pattern Matching, and Nested Lists

Tags: list, elixir

I'm going through Dave Thomas **Programming Elixir** book, and I am confused about some of the results in the pattern matching section of the book. In particular, take the following example: `[a] = [[1, 2, 3]]`

My interpretation is that the match should **succeed**, but the value of `a` should be `[1, 2, 3]`; instead, it is `[[1, 2, 3]]`.

Can someone help explain to me how the result came to be the value of the entire right-hand side of the match operator? Why is the output of `a = [[1, 2, 3]]` no different than the output of `[a] = [[1, 2, 3]]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it's different.
When you pattern match

```
[a] = [[1, 2, 3]]
```

then `a` became `[1, 2, 3]`. You are right about that. 
What you see as an output in `iex` is just the way console show it. If you check value of `a` it would be `[1, 2, 3]` as expected.

When you match

```
a = [[1, 2, 3]]
```

then `a` became `[[1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: To clarify: after every expression, iex prints the return value. The return value of a match happens to be the entire matched value.